# How can we set catch exception in a label?

Tags: c#, exception

My Class

```
 public string Countryadd(string country, string id)
     {

         string data = "0";
         try
         {


             string qry1 = "select Country from Country where Country='" + country + "'";//Checking weather txtcountry(Country Name) value is already exixst or not. If exist return 1 and not exists go to else condition
             SqlDataReader dr = conn.query(qry1);
             if (dr.Read())
             {
                 return data = "1";
             }
             else 
             {

                 string qry = "insert into Country values('" + id + "','" + country + "')";
                 conn.nonquery(qry);
                 return data = "3";

             }

         }

         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             string x = ex.Message();
         }

         return data;
     }
```

this string value how can we set in a label

My button_click function is

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string str = mas.Countryadd(txtcountry.Text, txtid.Text);
        if (str == "1")
        {
            Response.Write("<script>alert('Country Already Exist!!!!')</script>");

        }
        else if (str == "3")
        {

            Response.Write("<script>alert('Country Added Succesfully')</script>");
        }
        else
        {
            Label1.Text = str;
        }
}
```

Comment: You can't, `Button1_Click` never has visibility of the exception message; you're not returning it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not the prettiest of code. Returning a string as a kind of status code is generally bad practice, because you don't know the range of possible values which can be returned, and what they mean. At the very least consider integer or even enum (which is named).

That being said, I would handle the check and the insert in separate methods, and catch the exception in the click event handler - let a single method have a single responsibility:

```
    private void AddCountry(string country, string id)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
        {
            string sql = string.Format("INSERT INTO Country (Id, Country) VALUES ('{0}', '{1}')", id, country);
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
            {
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }

    private bool Exists(string country, string id)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
        {
            string sql = "SELECT Count(*) FROM Country WHERE Country='" + country + "'";
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
            {
                int count = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

                return count >= 1;
            }
        }
    }

    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (Exists(txtcountry.Text, txtid.Text))
            {
                Response.Write("<script>alert('Country Already Exist!!!!')</script>");
            }
            else
            {
                AddCountry(txtcountry.Text, txtid.Text);
                Response.Write("<script>alert('Country Added Succesfully')</script>");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Label1.Text = ex.Message;
        }           
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Catch(Exception e)
{
Label.Text= e.Message;
}
```